# Number Triangles with alternating number

Tags: java, while-loop, nested

Hello All,

I was wondering if someone could help me with making a number triangle in Java that looks like the one below using nested while loops. Would someone be able to help me out?

4
56
789
1234
56789

I have a variable 'i' on the outer loop determining how many rows the triangle will be and a variable 'j' on the inner loop determine which number the triangle will begin with. the numbers have to stay between [1-9].

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to do this?

Comment: I have tried but i am not getting anywhere with it. I have started over three times and I am still not getting the things that i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, It Will Work... It accepts rows & number through user and in first for loop it runs the loop till the number of rows and second loop print the number as per the value of I in pattern and if condition to check if the number is 10 then reset the number with 1 to start the numbering again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows, number = 1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter no of rows");
        rows = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter no to start with");
        number = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(number + " ");
                ++number;
                if (number == 10) {
                    number = 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this program accept as many no of rows and start index of number as user want

Comment: I have to do it with nested while - loops which is the pain. do you mind if i use this? for my program?

Comment: in programming while and for loop is same just syntax are different  but this program will  understandable with for loop easily

Comment: if you like my try to provide a solution then accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try.. r is for number of rows and v is the value

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    int v = sc.nextInt();
    int i = v - 1;
    int j = 1;
    while(j != r + 1){ 
        int k = 0;
        int ans = 0;
        while( k < j){
            i = i + 1;
            if(i == 10){
                i = 1;
            }
            ans = ans * 10 + i;
            k = k + 1;    
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
        j = j + 1;
    }
```

Comment: This works amazing. I was wondering if it would be possible to have it ask someone for 2 numbers i being the size and j being the number it begins with. that way we can have as many rows as we would like starting with any number in [1-9] interval

Comment: @BennLaplante you can get this in my solution

Comment: Static solution it is better to provide dynamic solution

Comment: I did according to the requirement of the question!

Comment: @BennLaplante Try for user interface